# Selecting a range with two fields

Tags: sql

I have a table with a job # and a suffix.  The query i'm trying to create selects a range of job # / suffix entries where the suffix is dependant upon the job #.  So for example:

```
Job #              Suffix
--------           -----------
00000001           001
00000001           002
00000001           003
00000002           001
00000002           002
00000002           003
00000002           004
00000003           001
00000003           002
00000003           003
00000003           004
```

I have four inputs.  One pair is the starting job / suffix and then the ending job / suffix.  If the user inputs:

Starting: 00000001 / 002

Ending:  00000002 / 002

They'll get the following results:

```
Job #              Suffix
--------           -----------
00000001           002
00000001           003
00000002           001
00000002           002
```

I want to know if there's a simple way to do this in one select statement in my stored proc.  The only way I thought to do it so far would be to select the jobs first into a table variable then filtering the suffix with another query.

This seems simple, but having difficulty wrapping my brain around this one.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused why would the `003` suffix show if the ending suffix was `002`

Comment: think of the suffix as an extension of the job #.  The suffix is completely dependent on the job, so 00000001/003 would be in the range because it follows 00000001/002 which is the low range.  Almost think of the two fields as one serial number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do, but a quick guess is something like this..

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE ( job + suffix*0.001 )
BETWEEN (starting_job + suffix*0.001) AND (ending_job + suffix*0.001)
```

This works, because it seems as if suffix is minor number. Essentially, you're serializing to "job.suffix" and selecting where you between the range of the set. If you can, create an index on `(start_job + suffix*0.001)`. This also assumes suffix is of `numeric(3)`

Comment: Alternatively, you could multiply the first by a thousand and add the second. That would probably be faster as you'll avoid the need for floating point comparison.

Comment: This would work for values that happen to be numeric, and don't overflow. But for a more general case you'll need to do it as strings.

Comment: True, I'm assuming none of these overflow, or are non-numeric.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (jobnum varchar(10), suffix varchar(3))

INSERT INTO @t (jobnum, suffix) VALUES ('00000001', '001')
INSERT INTO @t (jobnum, suffix) VALUES ('00000001', '002')
INSERT INTO @t (jobnum, suffix) VALUES ('00000001', '003')
INSERT INTO @t (jobnum, suffix) VALUES ('00000002', '001')
INSERT INTO @t (jobnum, suffix) VALUES ('00000002', '002')
INSERT INTO @t (jobnum, suffix) VALUES ('00000002', '003')
INSERT INTO @t (jobnum, suffix) VALUES ('00000002', '004')
INSERT INTO @t (jobnum, suffix) VALUES ('00000003', '001')
INSERT INTO @t (jobnum, suffix) VALUES ('00000003', '002')
INSERT INTO @t (jobnum, suffix) VALUES ('00000003', '003')
INSERT INTO @t (jobnum, suffix) VALUES ('00000003', '004')

DECLARE @Startjob VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Startsuf VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @Endjob VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Endsuf VARCHAR(3)
SET @Startjob='00000001'
SET @Startsuf='002'
SET @Endjob='00000002'
SET @Endsuf='002'

;WITH raw AS 
(
SELECT jobnum, suffix, ind=RIGHT('0000000000'+ISNULL(jobnum,''),10)+RIGHT('000'+ISNULL(suffix,''),3)
    FROM @t
)
SELECT *
    FROM raw
    WHERE ind BETWEEN 
        RIGHT('0000000000'+ISNULL(@Startjob,''),10)+RIGHT('000'+ISNULL(@Startsuf,''),3)
        AND 
        RIGHT('0000000000'+ISNULL(@Endjob,''),10)+RIGHT('000'+ISNULL(@Endsuf,''),3)
```

There's a bunch of extraneous string manipulation in there in order to handle short-length and null values.

Comment: you can modify mine to handle nulls using `( coalesce(job_range*1000,0) + coalesce(suffix,0) )`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just combine the where clauses from your 2 queries into 1.

Something like

```
SELECT ...
WHERE 
     JOB# BETWEEN '00000001' and '00000002'
AND  Suffix BETWEEN '001' and '002'
```

EDIT: 
  After your update I would do

```
SELECT ...
WHERE 
     JOB# + Suffix BETWEEN '00000001002'+ and '00000002002'
```

I assume values are strings with the leading 0's

Comment: This won't work, see my question above a section `003` on job `00000001` should return between `00000001 / 002`, `00000002 / 002`

Comment: Yeah, I saw the update. You beat my update after the question update ... I think appending the strings as such will be the easiest way to do this. You can append the inputs together with + if you want or just combine them before passing in

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something with a calculation in the where clause.

```
SELECT Table1.JOB, Table1.SUF
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.JOB)>="00001" And (Table1.JOB)<="00002") AND (([JOB] & [SUF])>="00001002" And ([JOB] & [SUF])<="00002002"));
```